# How to implement sectionning by date in an android listview?

Tags: android, listview

I want to group my Items in a ListView by date, the header of each section is the item date and other items with the same date must be in the section.

I don't know how much section I will get so I need to create sections dynamically.

my Item implementation is

```
public class Item 
{

   private String name;
   private Date date;
   /*....*/
}
```

How can I implement this.?

Comment: Sort them and populate the listview with the sorted list? Can't think of any other way right now.

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sectioned-listview-with-search_6865.html

Answer (score 0):

I think **Expandable list view** is also good alternative to you. try this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

you can group items related to date. when you click on parent(date) all its childs(items related to the date) will apper.